# Expire Documents at a Certain Clock Time in mongodb with php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have this code inside my php:

```
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->selectDB('authentication');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'digits');
    $document = array( 
        "username" => $_POST['username'], 
        "digits" => $_POST['digits']
        );
    $collection->insert($document);
```

I want these documents to be deleted after 2 hours automatically using ttl feature of mongodb.
there may be thousands of documents inserting every minute, so I don't want them to get messy or buggy, I want them to be deleted independently in the same collection.
If you can put the code in php I'd appreciate it. because everywhere else they just explained mongodb commands directly, which I couldn't understand how to use it in php. thanks.

**Edit 1:**
with the help of "Christian P", I created 30 documents for test:

```
    for($i=0;$i<30;$i++){
        $m = new MongoClient();
        $db = $m->selectDB('authentication');
        $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'teeeest');
        $collection->ensureIndex(array('createdAt' => 1, 'expireAfterSeconds' => 60));
        $document = array( 
                    "username" => "4563678678", 
                    "digits" => "5958974",
                    "createdAt" => new MongoDate()
                    );
        $collection->insert($document);

        sleep(1);
    }
```

but they are not being removed. 
an example of created documents:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53ac7c237fae31100e000109"
    },
    "username": "4563678678",
    "digits": "5958974",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2014-06-26T20:01:39.000Z"
    }
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53ac7c247fae31100e00010a"
    },
    "username": "4563678678",
    "digits": "5958974",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2014-06-26T20:01:40.000Z"
    }
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53ac7c257fae31100e00010b"
    },
    "username": "4563678678",
    "digits": "5958974",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2014-06-26T20:01:41.000Z"
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
as "Christian P" said in his edit, "expireAfterSeconds" should be passed as an array.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @ThomasRuiz: no I don't mean the whole code. I meant like myself from $m = new MongoClient(); to $collection->insert($document); it wouldn't be more than 10 lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To automatically [expire data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) from collection by setting TTL you must do two things:

1. Create a `Date` field.
2. Create a TTL index on that field.

To create a Date field in PHP you need to use MongoDate object:

```
$document = [ 
    "username" => $_POST['username'], 
    "digits" => $_POST['digits'],
    "createdAt" => new MongoDate()
];
```

You can add a TTL index using [ensureIndex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.ensureindex.php) command, as other regular indexes.

```
$collection->ensureIndex(
    ['createdAt' => 1], ['expireAfterSeconds' => 7200]
);
```

The above command will add an index TTL index on the `createdAt` that will delete documents after 2 hours.

Comment: I didn't know about MongoDate(), thanks. and I realized that mongodb's timezone is -1 UTC, and the server's time is -8 UTC.
I changed the windows server's timezone to -1UTC, and for test I changed the ttl to 20 seconds and tried again. now they are being inserted at the right time, but still nothing happens. none of them were removed even after more than five minutes.

Comment: @MDP sorry, my mistake :/ I was typing fast and I didn't add the options for the index as an array, so the regular index was created instead. See my edit.